# C2143 missing ';' before '*' & C 4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. note c++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

this code takes several input files, then it puts the lines within the input files in a linked list using getline function. I guess there is a problem about the creating the linked list because it is giving an error ***"error C2039: 'down' : is not a member of 'Functions "*** alongside specified errors on the title. I have no idea about ***C2130 & C4430*** errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "strutils.h" 
using namespace std;

struct Functions
{
    string fname;
    Functions *right;
    Commands  *down;
};
struct Commands
{
    string command;
    Commands *next;
};

Functions *head = nullptr;
Functions *temp = nullptr;

void printLinkedList()
{
    Functions *ptr = head;
    while (ptr != nullptr)
    {
        cout << ptr->fname << endl;
        while (ptr->down != nullptr)
        {
            cout << ptr->down->command + " ";
            ptr->down = ptr->down->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
        ptr = ptr->right;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to forward declare the `Commands` structure:

```
struct Commands;

struct Functions
{
    string fname;
    Functions *right;
    Commands  *down;
};
struct Commands
{
    string command;
    Commands *next;
};
```

Comment: Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Add a forward declaration of `Commands` before `Functions`:

```
struct Commands;
struct Functions {
   ...
}
```